# pip install virtualenv, error on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: python, 15.04, pip, virtualenv

How to fix this issue? and how to install pip and virtualenv on ubuntu 15.04

```
 pip install virtualenv
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
        load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 521, in load_entry_point
        return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2632, in load_entry_point
        return ep.load()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2312, in load
        return self.resolve()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2318, in resolve
        module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
        from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
        from pip.download import path_to_url
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
        from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
    ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you recently install the latest version of the python-package `requests`?

That one is incompatible with the old `pip` version shipped with Ubuntu!

You need to reinstall the *current* version of `pip` and everything will be fine:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Or if you have those issues with Python3:

```
sudo easy_install3 pip
```

You should always keep your python packages up to date with the current versions from PyPI (using `pip` or its ancestor `easy_install` while `pip` is broken) instead of using `apt-get`, as the Ubuntu repositories are pretty much behind the state of art.

Use `sudo pip install --upgrade INSERTNAMEOFPYTHONPACKAGEHERE` for every package you use to get an up-to-date environment.

Comment: omg thx for response :D anyway what easy_install is? where did they came from? i never install them (sudo apt-get install easy_install), but when i copy and paste that line work like charm

Comment: `easy_install` is a part of your python installation, like `pip`. It's located in the python package `setuptools`, which is represented by the Ubuntu package `python-setuptools` (probably outdated though), if you install it with `apt-get`. `easy_install`'s purpose is like `pip`'s to install python packages. It is older than `pip` and differs in some features, but for the daily use, `pip` is better. I just use `easy_install` where pip does not work, e.g. here because it's broken.

Comment: you mean by that easy_install is set by default on ubuntu? if pip i think must do "sudo apt-get install python-pip" first that we can use pip. i just wondering why that easy_install works like charm :D

Comment: Not sure, I thought pip is installed by default, too... It is just that the newest version of  python's `requests` removes the `IncompleteRead` package on which the old pip version from the Ubuntu repositories still relies. That is why `pip` fails, but `easy_install` does not depend on this old package, so it still works and allows you to easily get the newes t`pip` version that is not depending on the removed package any more.

Comment: Mmh! I learnt something!